# Non-ionizing radiation

Tags: radiation

This is out there - But hear me out. There is a new device on the market that promotes baby sleep by playing white noise. The speaker is directly under the baby’s head while sleeping (separated by roughly an inch of mattress.) From what I understand, a radio speaker emits non-ionizing radiation and is not known to be harmful to humans. However, in a rapidly developing brain, is it wise to eliminate all forms of radiation for extending periods of time, (especially in such close proximity,) such as when sleeping?

Comment: You can't eliminate all forms of radiation.  Even in total darkness in an enclosed room, you are still bathed in more electromagnetic radiation than you can imagine.  Worry about real problems rather than making up imaginary things.  Worry about why you think it necessary to use a white noise source to get your baby to sleep - if the little one isn't sleeping there might be a problem.

Comment: @SolarMike:  Typical speakers work by generating a magnetic field corresponding to the audio.  That's electromagnetic radiation, and it is non-ionizing.

Comment: @JRE I spent many hours getting 3 kids to sleep - never used any cr*p like that... But if you find it useful...

Comment: One thing I found that worked was for the baby to hear my heartbeat - always seemed to get them...

Comment: @SolarMike:  I never said I used one with my kids.  If you'd read my other comments, you'd see that I don't think much of the gadgets, either.  But, I'm all for facing facts.  A speaker emits electromagnetic radiation.  Extremely low frequency, and at low levels, but it is there.  Also note that the device isn't advertised as though the electromagnetic waves are a good thing.  That's the OP's concern, brought about by all the scare mongering that goes on about radiation.

Comment: My profile picture is an example of just how omnipresent electromagnetic radiation is.  That picture was made in my garage, using only ambient 12GHz electromagnetic radiation.  I used **no** transmitter to illuminate the room, only what was naturally present.

Comment: Sounds like a scam.

Comment: @HarrySvensson:  White noise devices are nothing new as a sleep aid.  What do you think the "wind and wave" recordings are.  The "non-ionizing" radiation thing is **nothing*" to do with the white noise, and is the OP's own concern.  Speakers do generate an electromagnetic field - radiation.  People have gotten to be so scared of "radiation" that they fear anything related to it - and forget that they are surrounded by it, and bathed in it, and would die without it (think of the sun.)

Comment: @JRE Oooh, I thought that the products selling point was that it removed ionized radiation, now after I re-read it I can clearly see that it's just white noise sound which clearly isn't ionized, nor a scam, and OP is wondering if all ionized radiation should be removed. Serious sloppy reading on my part.

Comment: @HarrySvensson:  Nah.  Seriously confused OP.  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with engineering.

Comment: I want to apologize for the shaming you are getting about using a white noise generator to calm your child. It's unlikely that anyone here is an expert in infant behavior or psychology. My son and daughter have both used similar devices from time to time to calm a child and I had no concerns whatsoever about radiation. Good luck to you.

Comment: obligatory Dilbert cartoon: [He'll be and engineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8vHhgh6oM0).

Answer (score 1):

This is a hoax and might be so fake that it might not be on Snopes.com.  ( popular urban-legend truth-finder site)

Electromagnetic (EM) radiation energy is the product of frequency and field strength.

The sun is our biggest source of EM energy and it is what gives life to this universe. Yet we know the excess thresholds that cause harm.  The baby speaker is not even a close consideration.  Relax.

Reports of speaker magnets and power line radiation in the home and outdoor ambient have been verified to be unrepeatable.  So reports may be "out there" but are not to be considered valid unless independently verified to be repeatable.   I recall,  a researcher in 1979, reported that the location of breaker panels in the home promoted illness in children from the high density of wires. It was in Popular xyz technical magazines back then and I recall 20 yrs later of that researcher had been convicted of fraud.  Selection bias is the usual cause of skewed results. The researcher used biased results to obtain US gov't grants.

The International Agency for Research on Cancer (IARC) began in 1969. In 2002 they published volume 80 of 120 entitled,  *Non-Ionizing Radiation, Part 1: Static and Extremely Low-Frequency (ELF) Electric and Magnetic Fields*.    This included natural and man-made EM radiation everywhere from hospitals to schools, power-substations, appliances, the biophysical relevance of induced fields.  It discussed the effects on reproductive and human development as well as experiments on rodents.  They examined any possible effects including; Immunological, Haematological (blood), Neuroendocrine (brain), Behavioural and physiological, Genetic, Genotoxic, and in-vitro effects.

**Conclusion**

> "There is little experimental or theoretical evidence that mutations could be directly caused by ELF magnetic fields (*even at levels far above ambient levels)*.  Exposure levels for the general population from man-made sources are typically 5–50  V/m  for electric fields and  0.01–0.2  μT for magnetic fields. It should be noted that the earth’s magnetic field (25–65 μT, from equator to poles)is a static field to which everyone is exposed."
>
> - There is **limited** evidence in humans for the carcinogenicity of extremely low-frequency magnetic fields in relation to childhood leukaemia.
> - There is **inadequate** evidence in humans for the carcinogenicity of extremely low-frequency magnetic fields in relation to all other cancers.
> - There is **inadequate** evidence in humans for the carcinogenicity of static electric or magnetic fields and extremely low-frequency electric fields.
> - There  is **inadequate** evidencein experimental animals for the carcinogenicity of extremely low-frequency magnetic fields.
> - No data relevant to the carcinogenicity of static electric or magnetic fields and extremely low-frequency electric fields in experimental animals were available.
>
> Static electric and magnetic fields and extremely low-frequency electric fields are not classifiable as to their carcinogenicity to humans.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/EM_spectrumrevised.png/1200px-EM_spectrumrevised.png

Comment: I've seen people claiming that above 0.1uT exposure has links to childhood cancers. But they probably just wanted to sell you [one of these](https://www.safespaceprotection.com/product/safespace-ii/)

Comment: A friend who is an educated mature Charter Accountant bought a device to contain the effects of cell phone radiation reaching the body.  He  asked me if it was legit. Cell phone power levels have reduced significantly since they first started and the power intensities are far below safe non-ionizing levels and his gadget was just another fake product.

Answer (score 0):

**All objects** which aren't at -273 Celcius (zero Kelvin, the absolute lowest temperature which can exist) emit radiation, I'm talking about **heat** radiation which is Infra-Red "light".

Also the universe is full of radiation.

Also nearly all electrical equipment radiates electro magnetic (EM) waves.

So radiation cannot be avoided.

The real question is if the radiation is harmful.

The speaker-gadget that you mention should not be harmful in any way as the EM waves it will emit are extremely weak and very low in frequency.

If you have WiFi in your home that will probably generate a lot more EM energy. In general these WiFi access point do not cause issues as the energy levels of the waves they generate are quite small.

If such "radiation" is harmful is an endless discussion because it is easy to prove something is harmful yet it is impossible to prove that something is safe. No matter how many tests are done there is always a case that wasn't tested.

So no, you don't have to worry about any radiation from the device being harmful.

In my opinion as a father, babies shouldn't need any help sleeping. Anything they get used to now might be an issue in the future. But I had nothing to complain regarding our babies sleeping so this is just my 2 cents.

Comment: It is funny how the up and downvotes cancel out to zero. Also funny is that none of the downvoters can present any arguments **why** they're downvoting. In my opinion downvoting an answer without giving a proper reason is just trolling and pointless. If you disagree I would still like to hear your arguments so we can all learn something.

Answer (score 0):

The main/only emissions will be magnetic. I'm sure the device is probably quite small and low powered. So the amount of magnetic radiation exposure would be tiny. Probably quite difficult to actually detect it at all from the other side of a mattress.

A few seconds in direct sunlight will expose you to more radiation than a life time of sleeping with a tiny speaker under your mattress.

We are exposed to a lot of radiation from many different sources. Electromagnetic **field** radiation is currently considered quite safe (by most people, but if you search the internet you will find plenty telling you how horribly dangerous it is). Regardless, it is safer than sunlight by a fair margin.

I should also point out that 'non-ionising radiation' is emitted by practically everything. What you're interested in/ worried about is Electomagnetic Fields (EMF), which any thing running on elecrticity, including the human body produce.

When people hear '**radiation**' they immediately think of harmful things like X-Rays, Gamma rays, radioactive waste, etc. Which is why I imagine you feel worried about it. Radiation is just what any energy flying around is called, be it heat, light, x-rays, etc. It's sort of like 'mushrooms', some mushrooms can kill you, but others are perfectly safe to eat yet they are all called a mushroom.

But I'm not going to tell you it's definitely not harmful. I haven't performed any tests on this device myself nor read any studies on the effects of ultra low power magnetic fields on babies. The best I can do is say I think it's probably safe and I wouldn't be worried about using it myself.

Comment: Sunlight **is** electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, but you know what I meant... Fixed.

Comment: Knowing what you **meant** should not be your goal when writing. Inexperienced readers, such as the OP, can easily be confused so it's very important that you write clearly.

Comment: I don't disagree. But I'm happy for people to just edit my post :p

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the insight, as this is not my field of expertise. For those who might be curious, the device is called the Snoo. I had to return to full-time work shortly after birth and enlisted this as help. I can say with absolute certainty that it works. The baby is sleeping well and absolutely flourishing, but I had recent concerns about the possible long-term impacts. I do apologize for being off topic, but I must admit that your responses fascinated me. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @Steph no problem, I think it's fairly natural to be concerned when you hear something is potentially bathing your babies head in radiation. Especially without a science back-ground. It does sound scary.